# How to give color to a particular text in the Qmenu Bar

Tags: html, qt, qmenubar

I am setting the title of the one the menu option as mentioned below:

QString Str = "User Profile: " + loFile.baseName();
m_titleBar->m_UserProfileMenu->setTitle(Str);

Here my requirement is, I need to change the font color of the text loFile.baseName() which is been added as part of the title.

Is it possible to change of the color of this text?
Examples would be helpful...

Comment: Bharathi, I don't think it is possible with QAction. You might try subclass `QWidgetAction`, it it worth the effort.

Comment: I tried Rich text also something like this :                    QString text("UserProfile: <FONT COLOR=red>%1</FONT>");
         text.arg(loFile.baseName());      But this didnt work for me

Comment: @vahancho : Can u give me an example on that since I am very new to QT